# Getting a bootstrap-calendar component to work with Django

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap

I don't know if this question is too specific but I'll give it a shot anyway:

I found a very nice bootstrap calendar that is very useful. The component is found here: http://bootstrap-calendar.azurewebsites.net/

I am trying to populate that calendar with events. I am using django. I made a function to return the elements on JSON format. I am making up the dates for now, just so its easier to view on the calendar for now:

```
def view_list_json(request):
i = 0
json_string = '{"sucess": 1, result: ['
for run in Model.objects.all():
    start = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days = i)
    end = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days = i) + datetime.timedelta(minutes = 40)

    start_str = str(int(time.mktime(start.timetuple())))
    end_str = str(int(time.mktime(end.timetuple())))

    json_string += '{ "id": "' + str(run.id) + '"'
    json_string += ', "title": "Foo"'
    json_string += ', "url":"#"'
    json_string += ', "class": "event-success"'        
    json_string += ', "start":"' + start_str + '"'
    json_string += ', "end":"' + end_str + '"},'
    i += 1
    json_string = json_string[:-1]
    json_string += ']}'

    return HttpResponse(json_string, content_type="application/json")
```

JSON format I am trying to create:

https://github.com/Serhioromano/bootstrap-calendar/blob/master/events.json.php

The component seems to be reading this function correctly. I don't get any errors in this sense on Firebug console...

... Yet the data doesn't seem to load.

Any ideas on how I can approach the problem?

Comment: Try adding `mimetype="application/json"` to your HttpResponse.  Quite a few javascript libraries look for the mimetype even though you would think the content_type would be sufficient.

Comment: I tried, it didn't go =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This JSON is not valid at all. There are quite a few problems, like extra close braces after each element, missing commas between elements, and missing open square brackets at the beginning of the next element.

But really you shouldn't be trying to build up a JSON string like that - it's too prone to errors. Even if you're hard-coding them, you should still build it up using standard Python lists and dicts, then serialize using the built-in `json` library.

Comment: Are you positive? Here is a generated output for one record. Can you kindly pinpoint me where the error is? 


{"sucess": 1, result: [{ "id": "1", "title": "Foo", "url":"#", "class": "event-success", "start":"1383855193", "end":"1383857593"}]}

As for your other comment, I tried to use the json library in python. Do I need to build the structure as a dictionary first and then use json.dumps(dictionary) in order to do it properly? I tried doing it using those helpers and I couldn't solve it.

Comment: That's valid for a single element, but not for multiple ones (try it). But yes, as I say build up a dictionary and then dump it to JSON.

Comment: I looked for a JSON validator and my original JSON had a problem the 'result' output, which wasn't in " ". The validators detected that. I used a couple more and ran it with two elements, and it approved. 

{"sucess": "1", "result": [{ "id": "1", "title": "Foo", "url":"http://www.example.com", "class": "event-success", "start":"1383857257", "end":"1383859657"},{ "id": "2", "title": "Foo", "url":"http://www.example.com", "class": "event-success", "start":"1383770857", "end":"1383773257"}]}

Now I am getting an error on the script: Uncaught Error. 

I will try the dictionary approach to test....