# How to add calendar events with Django-Bootstrap-Calendar?

Tags: django, calendar, twitter-bootstrap-3

Django-Bootstrap-Calendar (https://github.com/sandlbn/django-bootstrap-calendar) is a Django implementation of this calendar application: http://bootstrap-calendar.azurewebsites.net/

However, I can't figure out how to add events to the calendar via Django. The "non-Django" bootstrap calendar is rather simple, you just add events to the JSON file that gets loaded.

Has anyone here added events to Django-Bootstrap-Calendar before? I emailed the author of the project, however, he never responded to me.

The closest post I found to my question is here: [Getting a bootstrap-calendar component to work with Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19845092/getting-a-bootstrap-calendar-component-to-work-with-django) However, the author figured out how to add entries to the non-Django calendar only.

Edit: I figured out how to add events via the Admin panel.
In models.py, you simply add:

```
###Admin
class CalendarEventAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["title", "url", "css_class", "start", "end"]
    list_filler = ["title"]

admin.site.register(CalendarEvent,CalendarEventAdmin)
```

Then, in the admin panel you can add events (ultimately, I want non-admin users and anonymous visitors to be able to register events on the Calendar.)

However, this reveals a larger problem: the calendar doesn't display.

Edit 2: I have the calendar loading now by adding

```
{% load bootstrap_calendar %}
{% bootstrap_calendar_css %}
{% bootstrap_calendar_js language="template" %}
{% bootstrap_calendar_init language="template" %}
<!-- {% bootstrap_controls 'optional-css-classes' %} -->
{% bootstrap_calendar 'optional-css-classes' %}
```

to my index.html file. However, the calendar doesn't display the event(s) created with the Admin Panel.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to let other users add events, and not just admins through the admin panel?

Answer (score 1):

Simply put

```
{% bootstrap_calendar_init language="template" %}
```

after

```
{% bootstrap_calendar 'optional-css-classes' %}
```